# How to fix this sort method?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Here is the sort method for sorting words by second char and it is dosnt work(
Can anyone say how to fix it?

```
out = new StringTokenizer(input.toString());
n = out.countTokens();
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  wordList.add(out.nextToken());
}
Collections.sort(wordList, new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    return compare(o1.substring(1, 2).compareTo(o2.substring(1, 2)));
  }
});
```

Comment: What is an example of input that it doesn't work for?

Comment: You should accept an answer to your last question.

Comment: With rank =3 he/she wait until tomorrow to accept answer

Comment: It shouldn't be `compare(o1.substring(1, 2).compareTo(o2.substring(1, 2)))`, it should be `o1.substring(1, 2).compareTo(o2.substring(1, 2))`. Please accept an answer on your previous question.

Comment: @antoxa2584 - No problem. good luck with the rest of the project!

Comment: @Perception Rest is done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
Collections.sort(wordList, new Comparator<String>() {
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
return o1.substring(1, 2).compareTo(o2.substring(1, 2));
}
```

Instead of this:

```
Collections.sort(wordList, new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    return compare(o1.substring(1, 2).compareTo(o2.substring(1, 2)));
  }
```

The reason the former works is that the Comparator class's compare function takes objects from the Collection and expects the operations within to yield 0 to represent equality, 1 when the first parameter is "greater" and -1 when the second parameter is "greater". So, in the function you abstractly define what makes one object larger/equal/lesser than another.

Cheers.

Comment: I think if would be very helpful to future visitors if you preemptively explain what is happening.